# How to hide a custom field from admin?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, customization

I created a custom field that I would like to hide from the wp-admin (because the system generates it and I don't want user to change it; Hidding it with CSS should be OK in this case),

Like this,

```
 'postal_address' => array(
                            'guid' => 'postal_address',
                            'control' => array(
                                'type' => 'text',
                                'default' => '',
                                'allow_empty' => false
                            ),
                            'label' => 'Postal Address',
                            'help'  => 'Postal Address of Apartment'
                        ),
```

Wich works,

Problem is that the html element doesn't have any id/class so I can select it and Hide it,

Is there a way to add an html attribute from the definition?

thanks!

Comment: How did you create the custom field? It seems like you might be using a plug-in, if so you might want to say that ;)

Comment: YES! true, I should had mention, some reason I thought it would be using standard wp functions anyway, I will rewrite the question.. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're automatically populating a custom field, you can put an underscore at the beginning of the name ("_postal_address") to hide it in the admin UI.

Comment: Hey! thanks for you answer, but in the code I would need to use the '_name' aswell? thanks again (because I have allready many values stored). BTW: Do you mean in the index? or in the GUID attribute?

Comment: You should be able to just update the value with update_post_meta(). See http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

I don't recognize what your sample code is trying to do, but it looks like it's trying to define a user interface for this field. You won't need that.

Comment: @DaveRoss I believe the OP is actually using a plug-in so it's not clear what translates to the meta key. It may not be possible. But when using only core, you're right (although you can use this filter too: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.8/wp-includes/meta.php#L900)

Comment: Using an underscore is a horrible way to hide a custom field. A custom field's visibility should not in any way be coupled to its key.